# How to deploy ionic 4 app on firebase console?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, npm

Not Able to deploy my actual ionic app on firebase console.

Steps which I have performed : -

- Create a new ionic project
- firebase init
  -firebase deploy

but I am not able to view ionic output

Also, attach CMD screenshot and deployment screen
[image]

[image]

Comment: Follow this guide - really good for what u need: https://www.joshmorony.com/hosting-an-ionic-pwa-with-firebase-hosting/

Comment: Answer : 

1. ionic build

2. Firebase init (give below answer)
- Are you ready to proceed? Yes
- What do you want to use as your public directory? www
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
- File www/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No

3. firebase deploy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Inside ionic project)
PS E:\PROJECT\Project Angular\business-card-user - Copy> ionic build
> ng run app:build

Date: 2019-02-15T11:14:09.815Z
Hash: 19b812988985c5c367ab
Time: 32819ms
.
.
.
   DONE

PS E:\PROJECT\Project Angular\business-card-user - Copy> firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  E:\PROJECT\Project Angular\business-card-user - Copy

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Are you ready to proceed? Yes
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Ho
sting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, skipping

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? www
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? File www/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of www/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

+  Firebase initialization complete!
PS E:\PROJECT\Project Angular\business-card-user - Copy> firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'digitalvcard-user'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: found 1061 files in www
+  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: file upload complete
i  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: finalizing version...
+  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: version finalized
i  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: releasing new version...
+  hosting[digitalvcard-user]: release complete

+  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/........
Hosting URL: https://digitalvcard-user.firebaseapp.com
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to build the project. I usually do

`ionic cordova build browser` Or `ionic build`

This command creates a www directory in which all the files needed by Firebase are located. You should verify that the public property of the firebase.json is set to the folder.

Then you do ´firebase deploy´

Hope it helps!

Comment: Right answer ikerllo

Comment: Yes this is what worked for me and I didn't see it in doc.  Changed "public" to "www"

Answer (score 4):

**Find out your answer from given below URL and perform step as it is**

URL: 
https://www.djamware.com/post/5b74e54f80aca74669894413/ionic-4-and-angular-6-tutorial-firebase-realtime-crud-mobile-app#ch-1

Comment: Expected Answer, step by step solution. Thanks Parin

Answer (score 0):

What you deployed is content created by `> Firebase init`
You need to upload content from your ionic app, so you need to run following command

```
> ionic build
```

Wait till it a success message.

```
> Firebase deploy.
```

Hope this helps.